# Selenium setup with drone.io 0.6

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, drone.io

I'm trying to set up Selenium testing for my node.js app with `drone.io` following this example: http://docs.drone.io/selenium-example/.

My `.drone.yml` looks like this:

```
pipeline:
  test:
    image: node:latest
    commands:
      - yarn install
      - yarn build
      - yarn start
      - yarn test

services:    
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
```

And I'm using [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver/) like this:

```
const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
  .usingServer(`http://selenium:4444/wd/hub`)
  .build();

describe('Home page', () => {
  before(async () => await driver.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8080`));  // FIXME
  it('should render greeting', async () => {
    const src = await driver.getPageSource();
    chai.expect(src).contains('Hey there!');
  });
  after(async () => await driver.quit());
});
```

Now, the problem is that Selenium doesn't know URI the app running at (obviously, `http://127.0.0.1:8080` doesn't work since it's the different container). Is there a way to specify the hostname of the container running the pipeline in drone? Or to make the main container accessible from services in some other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to download `drone/drone:latest` to ensure you have the latest set of patches (or `drone/drone:0.7` or higher for those reading this in the future).

Using the yaml in your example (copied below) selenium will be able to access your node application at `http://test:8080` where `test` is the name of the pipeline step and network hostname.

```
pipeline:
  test:
    image: node:latest
    commands:
      - yarn install
      - yarn build
      - yarn start
      - yarn test
services:    
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
```

Another tip is to make sure that `yarn start` is non-blocking and does not block the shell session. For more details see http://veithen.github.io/2014/11/16/sigterm-propagation.html.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for fixing this Brad, it now works great!